# Sqoop import data from mysql, job does not start

Tags: sqoop, hadoop2

I am using using sqoop 1.4.7 with Hadoop multi node cluster.
I have a problem with sqoop import (sqoop list-tables and list-databases work fine). I have a Name Node and 2 data nodes in separate VM (ubuntu).

When I execute the sqoop import, it stops at

```
INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1559401109250_0003
```

and does not continue the process and nothing will be found in the HDFS!

PS:

```
I added the mysl-connector-java bin.jar!
I can add other files to my HDFS normally.
```

What can I do to fix this?